# R kernel is not available in Jupyter Notebook after install

Tags: r, jupyter-irkernel

I have installed Python 2.7, R 3.2.5, RStudio, Eclipse with PyDev, Jupyter Notebook 4.0.4. I use Windows 10 x64.

I did everything according to http://irkernel.github.io/installation/ and there were no errors. When I start Jupyter Notebook, there is no R kernel in dropdown list. When I type jupyter-kernelspec list, it shows:

Available kernels:

python2    c:\python27_64\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\resources
  ir         C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\ir

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I solve this in that way.

1) Reinstall kernel.

2) Reboot Windows.

3) Open Jupyter Notebook from path C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\ir

It works and it can be launched from any folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can hand edit the kernel condigs if needs be. Make a
`.ipython/kernels/<kernel-name>/kernel.json`

and add something like this

`{
 "display_name": "Julia",
 "language": "julia",
 "argv": [
    "julia",
    "-i",
    "-F",
    "/User/<user>/.julia/v0.3/IJulia/src/kernel.jl",
    "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "codemirror_mode":"julia"
}`

but for R!