# R kernel after installation was freezing and did not respond

Tags: r, jupyter-lab, jupyter-irkernel

I have installed IRkernel for Jupyter Lab. This is the line of code, which I used for this aim:

```
install.packages(c('repr', 'IRdisplay', 'evaluate', 'crayon', 'pbdZMQ', 'devtools', 'uuid', 'digest'))
install.packages('IRkernel')
#Make Kernel available to Jupyter
IRkernel::installspec()
```

When I have opened new notebook in R kernel, it was freezing, trying to connect with no success and then messaged that there was no kernel. After that I reinstalled all IRkernel dependencies and actually IRkernel, restart Windows and again launch notebook, however the R kernel wasn't responding anymore.

I have read issue ['R kernel is not available in Jupyter Notebook after install'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37010406/r-kernel-is-not-available-in-jupyter-notebook-after-install), although it did not work for me. My R version 4.2.1, Windows PowerShell 1.15.3466.0, Jupyter Lab 3.5.2.

Please, help me to setup or build up from source R kernel for Jupyter Lab via pip or Windows PowerShell.